# Check whether string starts with "!" in POSIX sh

Tags: sh

Trying to create a condition based on whether the line starts with an "!".

Note: this is sh not bash

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $line = "!*" ] ;
then
    echo "$0: $line has !"
else
    echo "$0: $line has no !"
fi
```

Comment: BTW, you need to quote your expansions -- ie. in `[ "$line" = "!*" ]`, the quotes around `"$line"` are just as important as those around `"!*"`, even if you *did* want to just compare against the fixed string `!*`.

Comment: (to provide a specific example of a case where behavior without those quotes will fail, consider `line='1 = 1 -o 5'` -- that would behave identically to `[ 1 = 1 -o 5 = "!*" ]`, thus returning true even without a leading `1`).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In [POSIX `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), `=` performs exact string comparisons only.

Use a `case` statement instead.

```
case $line in
  "!"*) echo "$line starts with an exclamation mark" ;;
  *)    echo "$line does not start with an exclamation mark" ;;
esac
```

---

If you *really* want to put this in an `if`, you can do that:

```
if case $string in "!"*) true;; *) false;; esac; then
  echo "$line starts with an exclamation mark"
else
  echo "$line does not start with an exclamation mark"
fi
```

Comment: Also notice how the wildcard (obviously) needs to be outside the quotes.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the standard POSIX parameter substitution syntax.

`${var#repl}` will remove the `repl` from the beginning of the content of the `$var` variable.

So, you'll have:

```
$ var=test
$ echo ${var#t}
est
$ echo ${var#X}
test
```

So, in order to have a simple `if` statement to check if a variable starts with a string (`!` in your case), you can have:

```
#!/bin/sh

if test "$line" = "${line#!}"; then
    echo "$0: $line has no !"
else
    echo "$0: $line has !"
fi
```

PS: `test ...` is equivalent to `[ ... ]`, so the above script is exactly the same as

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$line" = "${line#!}" ]; then
    echo "$0: $line has no !"
else
    echo "$0: $line has !"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as `echo "$STR" | cut -c -1`.

```
#!/bin/sh

STR="!abcd"
if [ "!" = $(echo "$STR" | cut -c -1) ]; then
    echo "true"
fi
```

Comment: Without quotes outside the command substitution, this will cause an error when `STR` starts with whitespace or is empty.

Comment: That is to say, it should be `[ "!" = "$(echo "$STR" | cut -c -1)" ]`, not `[ "!" = $(echo "$STR" | cut -c -1) ]`. Word-splitting is suppressed by the ksh extension `[[` but not POSIX-standard `[`; quotes are still needed in the latter. (They're sometimes needed in the former too, but not for the same reason).